# Which git branches point to the current commit?

Tags: git

Currently, if I want to know the branches that point at the current commit, I use

`git show-ref | grep "<SHA1>"`

Where `<SHA1>` is the current commit.

This produces output like

```
<SHA1> refs/heads/branch-name1
<SHA1> refs/heads/branch-name2
<SHA1> refs/remotes/origin/branch-name1
```

Is there a simpler way to get the branches that point to the current commit? Something similar to

`git-ideal-command-without-parameters`

Which produces

```
branch-name1
branch-name2
origin/branch-name1
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git branch --points-at HEAD`

[`HEAD`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_HEAD) is a reference to the currently checked out commit.

[See `git-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) for more information.